# Jansson - unpack json with a null property

Tags: c, json, null

I have some problem with null value on unpack json object.
Suppose we have:

```
/* root is the JSON object {"foo": null, "quux": true, "val" : null} */
const char *str;
int boolean;
int val = 0;
json_unpack(root, "{s:s, s:b, s:i}", "foo", &str, "quux", &boolean, "val", &val);
```

How can I have the "*str" pointer to null and val = 0 instead go in core dump?

Comment: I guess your format at least should describe all 3 parameters

Comment: Yes, you're right. Have some idea about null value?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code that's dumping core? Even if NULL is not a valid value for an integer, Jansson's `json_unpack` should return -1. Try decoding one parameter at a time to see whether it works. Try also putting valid values in the JSON object to better circumscribe the problem.